# Laravel - Sessions not storing properly / Not persisting?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.7

In my `Page A`, I have:

```
session()->put('name','My Name');
```

and tests it via:

```
return session()->get('name');
```

And it displays `My Name`.

Now on my `Page B`, I returned the session:

```
return session()->get('name');
```

However now it displays null or " ". What am I doing wrong here?

PS: I'm using Laravel 5.7

## Update

Here's my `Page A` where I call the `session()->put`:

```
if(Hash::check($password, $user->password)){
    session()->put('name', $user->name);
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Success! '.session()->get('name')
    ]);
}
```

This displays `Success! My Name`

But when I go to `Page B` and have a:

```
$thename = session()->get('name');
return 'name = '.$thename;
```

I get `name =`

And more so, if I set the `name` on `Page B`:

```
session()->put('name', 'ASDF');
```

After the first load it will say `name = ASDF` on `Page B`. I delete the line: `session()->put('name', 'ASDF');` and refreshes the page, it still says `name = ASDF` so that means it's saving there.

If I go back to `Page A`, set the `name` again there, and go back to `Page B`, it still says `name = ASDF` not `name = My Name`

Comment: Where are you calling `session()->put()`? There are certain parts of Laravel where calling that doesn't actually set `session()` properly.

Comment: @TimLewis I've updated my question

Comment: @TimLewis Sorry, I'm calling both on the same controller but different routes. `Page A` is on `/login` while `Page B` is on `/getuser`

Comment: correction: Different functions on the same controller

Comment: Something like `public function login()` and `public function getUser()`? If so, that _should_ work, even if one is an AJAX request...

Comment: Yes, something like that. I don't really understand why it isn't :<

Comment: The specific place I'm referring to is `__construct()`; if you try to use `session()->get()` or `session()->put()` in that function, it won't persist (happens too early in the request lifecycle). With the code shown, I'm not too sure; maybe someone else will have more luck.

Comment: I know the reason - I store the session on the api routes of which I read somewhere that api routes cannot store session permanently.

Comment: Ah yes, if these are `api` routes, you shouldn't use `session()` as APIs are generally "stateless"

Answer (score 3):

Try manually saving the session (via `->save()`) after writing to the session.

**Example:**

```
session()->put('name', $user->name);
session()->save();
```

If that seems to resolve it, you're killing Laravel's request lifecycle somewhere. Laravel uses middleware to save any session data, therefore all session data is persisted at the end of the request lifecycle.

Are you using `dd` somewhere?